# How does arduino pro micro reset via USB?

Tags: usb, bootloader, reset

The pro micro has no hardware reset circuitry that would allow host PC to cause a reset via USB.  But when programming using the bootloader, the host PC must have a way to reset the pro micro to allow it to enter bootloader mode and then upload code.

How is it reset?  Is the pro micro sensing the serial rate in some kind of way?  And if so, what is it looking for?  Or does the PC just disconnect the USB and then reconnect (but surely this would not work if the board was externally powered)

[image: Schematic of pro micro]